# how to use Windows phone store test kit in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace, windows-phone-store, testkit

I am developing Windows Phone 7.1 app, and want to test it against marketplace requirements. So I use Marketplace test kit. However, when reading about [Windows Phone Store Test Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394032%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), I see that

> The Marketplace Test Kit installed with Windows Phone SDK 7.1 is
>   obsolete. Use the Store Test Kit installed with Windows Phone SDK 8.0
>   to test apps that target Windows Phone OS 7.1.

So how can I use Windows Phone Store Test Kit? I don't want to install Windows Phone 8 SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you not wanted to install WP 8 SDK. It installs side by side with the existing WP 7.1 SDK. You can have both the SDK's (in other words -- both the VS versions). So that you can develop in 7.1 and test using 8 SDK.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. But installing WP8 SDK requires Windows 8, which is not possible for me.